# Cuando hago click sobre Google chart y intento abrir una ventana nueva los pop-ups quedan bloqueados

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, eventos

Cuando el usuario clicka sobre el gráfico de google-chart llamo a este evento:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e){
                            self.selectHandler(chart, data);
                        });
```

Y después intento abrir una nueva ventana con la función `window.open`:

```
// open entity page
var newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
if (newTab) {
    newTab.focus();
} else {
    alert('Please allow popups for this website');
}
```

Pero los pop-ups de la página quedan bloqueados impidiendo que se abra la ventana.

Cómo puedo impedir que se bloqueen los pop-ups?
Gracias

Comment: Laia: Es probable que lo que esté bloqueando tus ventanas emergentes sea el navegador. En cualquier caso, es importante incluir lo que has buscado/investigado y en el caso de código que no funciona también se debe incluir un [mcve]. Si no lo has hecho aún, revisa [ask].